# What happens to the hooks-rules when a component is conditionally rendered

Tags: reactjs

The https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation states that do not conditionally call the hooks inside the component which I get it based on the explanation.

I would like to understand why it is ok conditionally render the component across multiple re-renders and how does that know to maintain the state value?

Comment: React associate state with hooks and relies on them to be called in the same order inside a component. The state is not shared between parent and child components, and next time you render the child again it will have new state.

Comment: Dan wrote about this topic in his blog. Give it a read https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/ . If you want an in-depth of how React work here https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova - I agree. But when you conditionally render a component from parent component none of the hooks of the child component which is conditionally rendered will be called. So, the order of hooks execution is changed when we add code like `showPopup && <Popup/>` as if `showPopup` is false none of the `Popip` hooks will be called.

Comment: @kunquan - They are great links. I believe the callIndex is used to keep the state information in a linked list (hence the sequence matters) and this linked list itself is stored in call tree if the tree changes the state is destroyed is what I understood from the article.